# Carregar um DLL de dentro de um jar

Tags: java, api, opencv

Olá, atualmente estou trabalhando com um projeto onde preciso criar uma API em java para processamento de imagem e após isso tenho que integrá-la em um módulo Mobile e um módulo web.

Porém quando tentei fazer a primeira integração, ocorreu um erro onde o programa acusa não encontrar a dll do Opencv (API que está integrada a minha) no momento de utilizar uma das classes da minha API. Gostaria de saber como carregar a dll do opencv que estou utilizando de dentro do jar da minha API.

Comment: Já verificou se a `dll` está na `PATH`? Está chamando o JNI todo correto? O mobile normalmente não suporta `dll` (biblioteca dinâmica do Windows), mas `so` para Android ou `dylib` para iOS.